# Script error in WebBrowser control

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Implementing  Webbrowser control in MFC VC++ application. when there are script errors on the page it displays all the time even when I un-select "Display a notification about every script error" in Internet Explorer. This control inherits the other options like "Show Images" from IE but not script errors.

I tried to debug "OnNavigateError()" and "OnNewBrowserWindow()" events but it still does not come here. I know in C# there is a property called "ScriptErrorsSuppressed" to disable script error in webbrowser control but how to do it in VC++. please help.

Comment: I have an exactly similar situation in hand. Tried the SetSilent() Property of the WebBrowser, however that tends to block literally everything, including Authentication dialog boxes. Let me know if you found something.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that you can never catch all errors and you should also consider displaying these annoying messages. After all, a WebBrowser control is not a browser and is used, many times, for a limited purpose (for example: I am using such for a mapping project). So you can just turn these messages off by calling:

```
m_Browser.put_Silent(TRUE);
```

You need to read the MSDN article: [How to handle script errors as a WebBrowser control host](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/261003/how-to-handle-script-errors-as-a-webbrowser-control-host) and add several include files

```
#include <Docobj.h>
#include <Mshtml.h>
```

And finally define:

```
DEFINE_GUID(CGID_DocHostCommandHandler,0xf38bc242,0xb950,0x11d1,0x89,0x18,0x00,0xc0,0x4f,0xc2,0xc8,0x36);
```

Answer (score -1):

MSDN provides some information on [How to handle script errors as a WebBrowser control host](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/261003).  That information worked for me.